# Specifiying values in a system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Suppose I have system of equations, for example

```
Clear[a, b, c]
Reduce[{RCI7[{a, b, c}] > 0, RCI7[{b, c, a}] > 0, RCI7[{c, a, b}] > 0}, {a, b, c}] // N
```

where `RCI7` is some function. The output is complicated so I would like to choose `a = 1` and try again, hence I may try

```
Clear[a, b, c]
a := 1;
Reduce[{RCI7[{a, b, c}] > 0, RCI7[{b, c, a}] > 0, RCI7[{c, a, b}] > 0}, {a, b, c}] // N
```

Of course, I get the error

> "1 is not a valid variable."

unless I remove a from the list of unknowns.

**My question**: is there a way to go around this without removing a from the list of unknowns of my system?

**Remark**: of course, in this example I could do that, but with more complicated systems with a lot of equations and variables, I may want to avoid modifying the system each time I try to specify one variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x = 1;

Reduce[
  x^2 - y^3 == 1, 
  DeleteCases[{x, y}, _?NumericQ]
]
```

or  in case when you want to set `x` to some kind of complex expression:

```
DeleteCases[Unevaluated@{x, y}, _?ValueQ]
```